# How do I obtain an OAuth token from WSO2 using the Consumer Key/Secret?

Tags: oauth, wso2

I am very new to WSO2 and am still evaluating it - mostly through Fiddler.  It is my understanding that I should be able to obtain an OAuth token by calling WSO2's Login API.  I have attempted various URLs (in Fiddler) along the lines of:

// Based off a blog post : http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.com/2012/11/generate-application-tokens-user-tokens.html

```
http://localhost:8280/login?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=PRODUCTION
Authorization: Basic cFNET0lab1RnMHRBODRCWmQ4bTRBbnp1c0RZYTpZREIzZzh3RXhQOV92ZTdZX1drYVhieWx5ZlVh
```

When I execute the above URL, I receive **(403) No matching resource found in the API for the given request**.

I can use the the "Access Token" (via the Bearer tag) and the APIs work.  I just can't figure out how to obtain the OAuth token for actual runtime use.

Any pointers/ideas?

--- Thanks, Jeff

Answer (score 2):

1. Setup Identity Server [`domain:9443`]
2. Create OAuth2 application, and get client id + consumer key
3. Get Base64 encoded of clientId:consumerKey - replace this for Authorization Basic xxxxx
4. Replace the REST endpoint for token generation - This you should get in oauth application on management console [in our case `https://domain:9443/oauth2/token`]

And below curl command should give you the response

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=sasikumar@domain.com&password=xxxx1234" -H "Authorization" -H "Authorization: Basic X2dhWllidkN6TDNQY2ZqSmVBQ1lsNlg2SFdRYTpSQVlSMmxOZzQ0enU5ZXVGSDRDVXdOUWRudlVh, Content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  https://domain:9443/oauth2/token
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access OAuth2 REST web service to access the token.Here is how you can access token using curl

```
curl --user ConsumerKey:ConsumerSecret  -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2endpoints/token
```

Comment: Hi Jeff,This is just to get a clear idea on your problem.The mentioned "Login API" in the blog is specific to WSO2 API Manager product.Hope you are trying with it.Whcih version of API Manager are you trying with? And according to the error you got "(403) No matching resource found in the API for the given request.",it seems a problem with your request url.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to do this with WSO2 API Manager.  I'm using the latest version as of about 2 days ago.

Comment: ajanthan, any idea what the query string and HTTP headers should look like so I can try this with Fiddler?  I've tried a few approaches but haven't found the correct one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using cURL tool available in linux by default ( you can install cURL for windows explictly)

curl -v 4 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=&password=&client_id=&client_secret=" https://:9443/oauth2/token

to obtain the client_secret & client_id you have to register a app in wso2is.

There are free tools available to construct the above request or directly use the above parameters and to get the token.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Identity Server [domain:9443]
Create OAuth2 application, and get client id , consumer key and url.

Process post request by using 'poster' with bellow details ,

URL :- which get from oauth application

Content Type :- application/x-www-form-urlencoded

body:- grant_type=password&username=your username&password=your password&client_id=your client id&client_secret=your client secret