# WSO2 IS - how make link with inline token for once logon?

Tags: oauth, wso2, token, wso2-identity-server

I need to generate or make url-link with inline token, that i can send to user email for only once login.

I found how get access_token for user for redirect to my endpoint ([How do I obtain an OAuth token from WSO2 using the Consumer Key/Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940936/how-do-i-obtain-an-oauth-token-from-wso2-using-the-consumer-key-secret)), but I don't understand what to do next. I found how validate token, refresh it, but nothing about logon by token.

I need something like https://my_wso2is/auth_token?token=37133621-f099-33c4-b686-c017ed229fc0

Answer (score 3):

You can use OIDC in order to get the user authenticated and then allow access to your application. You can find more information from [1] about how WSO2 IS works with OIDC using one of the sample applications named playground.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground

Comment: I don't understand. In paragraph 7:
`At this point the application receives the ID Token along with the Access Token. The ID Token is used to login the user to the application. Now you can see the logged in user.`
I don't see what I need to with this token in next.

Comment: Once you get the id_token, you can validate it and then use it to create a session for the user. id_token contains authenticated subject and other claims about the user.

Comment: How use it to create a session for the user?